# IP address change caused shard to be DOWN in mongo MMS

Tags: mongodb, ip, mongodb-mms

I have a sharded, replicated mongodb cluster. I'm in the process of re-IPing the shards to be on a different subnet. Just started by re-IPing one secondary mongod. It now has the new IP and I flushed the DNS. However in Cloud Manager, that server shows as DOWN now. 
What can I do to make MongoCloud see that server again? I know MongoCloud communicates with the shards via the mongo automation service that is installed on them, but I don't see any configuration in there about the IP address, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

there was a hardcoded hostfile always forcing the mongod server to the old IP address. Once the host file entries were removed, everything was OK. The host file (in Windows) is found in C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on the 2 other replica set members (I have a sharded env. w/ 1 primary and 2 secondaries).
The host file contains a line per entry, host   ip